# warning: "Signal <C> is used but never assigned"

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

me salio esto en ISE cuando realizaba mi programa: `Signal <C> is used but never assigned` y ya busque en varios foros y no entiendo muy bien el porque.
Quería ver si me podrían ayudar a entender porque se da y como puedo corregirlo, ya que es el unico error en mi código, por favor.
Les dejo mi codigo por si les sirve:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity CodMod6Desc is
    Port ( clk: in  STD_LOGIC;
              Sa: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0));
end CodMod6Desc;

architecture Behavioral of CodMod6Desc is
--VARIABLES DE APOYO--
signal con: integer range 0 to 25_000_000;
signal clk1: STD_LOGIC;
signal A, B, C :STD_LOGIC;
--------
begin
--Aqui configuramos el reloj que vaya a un segundo cada 25MHZ--
configurarReloj: process(clk)
    begin
        if clk 'event and clk = '1' then
           if con = 24_999_999 then
             con <= 0;
             clk1 <= (not clk1);
            else
                con <= (con +1);
            end if;
        end if;
end process configurarReloj;
--Aqui generamos el evento--

process (clk1)

begin

if clk1 'event and clk1 = '1' then
        A <= ((NOT A) AND (NOT B) AND C) OR (B AND (NOT C));
        B <= (A AND (NOT C)) OR (B AND C);
        C <=  C;
        end if;
        end process;
        
Sa(0) <= A;
Sa(1) <= B;
Sa(2) <= C;
end Behavioral;
```

Y este es el warning completo:

```
Line 15: Net <C> does not have a driver 
Signal <C> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value GND.
```

PD: Gracias por la ayuda!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener una cosa clara cuando implementas código en VHDL o verilog, y es que la programación no es secuencial, sino paralela.
En el proceso donde entra en juego tu señal `C`:

```
if clk1 'event and clk1 = '1' then
    A <= ((NOT A) AND (NOT B) AND C) OR (B AND (NOT C));
    B <= (A AND (NOT C)) OR (B AND C);
    C <=  C;
    end if;
    end process;
```

Cuanto tienes un flanco de reloj, va a asignar las señales `A`, `B` y `C` en función de los valores de las mismas. La primera vez que se ejecute este proceso, el sistema no va a tener constancia de qué valor toman las señales.

Para evitar este tipo de problemas te recomiendo utilizar biestables que actúen como registros que sean realimentados con las señales de salida de este proceso, por lo que sólo tendrías un flanco de reloj de latencia al comienzo del sistema, luego ya el sincronismo sería el mismo. Es simplemente un modo que permite a la FPGA saber el valor real de las señales y además te servirá para controlar mejor el valor de tus señales.

Saludos.